# Build my own CMS

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

I've read that it is not a good idea to build your own CMS unless it is for learning purposes. The main reason is because lack of security. Advanced CMSs spend a lot of time testing their CMS to make sure it is secured. My question is, What if I build my own CMS on well known frameworks such Laravel4, Zend, or Symphony? Wouldn't my CMS be secured?

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have time to spend to build a new framework?

Comment: Not a framework. I'm saying build my own CMS on a pre built framework such as Laravel4

Comment: It'll be secured if you write secure code.

Comment: I've made my own CMS multiple times and they're all pretty secure. you can do it, but you should look into securing connections and encrypting as much as possible.

Comment: @Quentin That is a dangerous game to play - relying on humans to write secure code is not a wise thing to do. We're notoriously bad at it.

Comment: What's the goal of your CMS ?

Comment: @iamde_coder How many attempted attacks have you logged against your custom CMS applications, and how many succeeded? Everything is secure if it never gets attacked.

Comment: Business CMS. I want to build it because I would have more control over it.

Comment: At work we have custom CMS for each site, and theses CMS are only accessible from work. So it depends but I can say yes, you can build your own cms for sure.

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo I've logged 186 attacks 2 were successful and have been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you like it that way,  you can build your secure CMS with a Framework depending how the secure framework is. For example which architect they use, hashing algorithms, escaping malicious code, Hijacking, Forgery, Database abstraction and PDO.

I can tell you about Zend Framework which is very secure  and mature framework and it uplifts a lot of heavy work. It has the most secure algorithms out of the box. If you know how to play with Zend Framework, i can be pretty sure that you can build secure CMS, because all best secure hole prevention mechanisms are out of the box. Just use them.

Hope that adds.

Answer (score 3):

Frameworks, like the ones you mentioned, provide tools to increase security, but they can't do the work for you. You will still be responsible for writing proper code, test for security holes, etc.

Compare it with a carpenter: good, high quality tools will help him get the job done, but he will still be the one *using* those tools.

Comment: That is very misleading. Frameworks do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. For instance, many frameworks handle the authentication side of things for you and you don't even have to think about it or handle it in the rest of your code. (By extension, this means you can't write insecure code with respect to authentication by accident.)

Comment: However, to continue the analogy, how many carpenters use tools they built themselves as opposed to ones they bought at Home Depot? Sure, they'd have more control if they built their own power saw, but it wouldn't be nearly as reliable.

Comment: Fair point, some frameworks can indeed handle some things for you. However, you still have to be very careful and know a lot about security to write a secure application / CMS.

Comment: To WRITE one, yes. To USE one, no. Mediawiki can be used as a CMS, and you don't need to know much at all about security to set that up effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Sure the Laravel4, Zend, or Symphony framework would be relatively secure, but the application/CMS you write will only be as secure as you write it. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just because its insecurities are not known does not mean it is more secure.

Published CMS may have some known vulnerabilties, but they also will have thousands or millions of hours of production use, and dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of attempted attacks against them. Those attacks allow the developers to shore up security for everyone's benefit.

So while your attack vectors may require more research than just hanging out on a hacker forum and finding out the latest security flaws in the Zend framework, there will be orders of magnitude MORE vulnerabilities for an attacker to find.